# Bitcode_strip failed in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I know there are few same question as this title, I try all given solution which are advised but not working in my case. Do anyone has any other solution for same?

I have tried below all options.

1) Remove all derived data and clean multiple times**

2) Change Xcode version**

3) Set STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO

4) All bit-code option in build setting are set to NO**

5) Check - uncheck "Rebuild from bitcode" option**

Do anyone has an idea why this option(Re-build from bit code in archive option) appear in only specific projects, this is not visible in all projects. I have checked two projects in which one has this option visible and another has not - I checked all setting of and found there are no any changes in settings so why this happen for two different projects?

Please share me if anyone has idea about same.

Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

It may be due to lack of disk capacity.
Try deleting the temp files.

Comment: yes, thank you. it worked for me! :D I had about 6gb free disk space. I deleted some files and I managed to upload a new binary to App Store.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitcode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2)

Go to project Settings and mark No against Enable Bitcode option.

[image: Build Options]

This is how it will appear while archiving.

[image]

Comment: I have already did that, I explain all option which I have tried in my code -
 but still I got same issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this :

1: All of the supplied libraries *have* to support Bitcode in order for the main target that includes them to support Bitcode

2: try to compile project with Bitcode enabled to check whether all of the dependencies support Bitcode.

> Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. For watchOS and tvOS apps, bitcode is required. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bitcode.
>   After you distribute your app using iTunes Connect

Comment: I have also tried this option as R&D but not worked because my SDKs are without bitcode. So I must set "bitcode enable NO"