# Xcode Carthage export error ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `toolsPath' for nil:NillClass> , bitcode_strip failed

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution

I am maintaining a project using **Carthage**. It runs fine and archives fine. But it failed to export enterprise app. The error in "Enterprise distribution options" is

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `toolsPath' for nil:NilClass>
```

If skip "Enterprise distribution options" page by clicking "Next" immediately, result in another error "**bitcode_strip failed**".

I had searched on stackoverflow, there are many related posts, but no question is the same as my situation so I post a new question.

I followed this post
[Bitcode_strip failed in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159026/bitcode-strip-failed-in-xcode-8)
but none of the following solutions works.

1. Remove all derived data and clean multiple times    **-- not work**
2. Change Xcode version (Xcode 9.2 and Xcode 8.3)      **-- not work**
3. Set STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO              **-- not work**
4. All bit-code option in build setting are set to NO  **-- not work**
5. Check - uncheck "Rebuild from bitcode" option       **-- not work**

I has found an answer and hope to help those who use Carthage. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54176241/111277).

[image: Enterprise distribution options]
[image: ipatool failed with an exception NoMethodError]
[image: Click "Next" before loading finish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete *.dSYM "*in Carthage/Build/iOS*" in **Build Phases** > **Copy Bundle Resources** 
[image]

Reference:

Ref(1) http://ka2n.hatenablog.com/?page=1458709290
[image]

Ref(2) https://twitter.com/steipete/status/725816245749166080
[image]

Ref(3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797244/111277